# Improve LAMP performance Ubuntu 12.0.4

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mysql, lamp, swap

```
cpu 1.3%
mem 476/490MB
swap 347/511mb

tasks: 43, 29 thr; 1 running
load average: 0.10 0.08 0.06

via htop:<br>
/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start (listed 8x @ 8.1% mem each)
/usr/sbin/mysqld (listed 24x @ 2.1% mem each)
```

if I restart apache, pages load much quicker. after few days, page load takes much longer.

running small wordpress site with < 100 daily visits on vps with 512mb. didn't run into this problem before transfer to vps. it was previously on shared hosting.

how can i improve performance without restarting each time? where should i start looking for potential issues? if **htop** doesn't provide enough information, what commands should i run to provide additional details?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LAMP Server Performance Tips](http://serverfault.com/questions/11739/lamp-server-performance-tips)

Comment: @yoonix i looked at the tips you linked but it help trying to figure out if htop is indicating any potential issues with the multiple listings.

Comment: nothing to do with your hardware

Comment: @Charles Please check this answer I provided to a similar question: http://serverfault.com/questions/551727/how-much-free-memory-should-i-have-on-my-webserver/551734#551734

Answer (score 2):

**Problem:** You are running a memory heavy web server application and a non-lightweight database on a single server with only 512M of memory and a 1:1 ratio of swap to RAM.

**Solution:** Get better hardware.

Comment: are you saying that a vps with 512mb can't handle one small wordpress site with less than 100 daily visits?

Comment: @Charles wordpress eats memory for breakfast and has lots of snacks on it thereafter.

Comment: WordPress is great but a memory hog. But that said, you can always performance tune Apache & MySQL to improve things without a RAM upgrade. But as the site grows it is inevitable that you will need one.